# Magento SQL Query to show product manufacturer

Tags: sql, magento

I am trying to query the Product Manufacturer in Magento 1.7.0.2 . I browse again and again all the table to where I can get the manufacturer table and connect it with product SKU.

I try this query to hope that I can get the manufacturers of the product:

```
SELECT 
eav_attribute_option_value.value FROM 
eav_attribute,
eav_attribute_option,
eav_attribute_option_value 
WHERE 
eav_attribute.attribute_code = 'manufacturer' AND
eav_attribute_option.attribute_id = eav_attribute.attribute_id AND
eav_attribute_option_value.option_id = eav_attribute_option.option_id
```

but it is not equal to the product manufacturer when I compare the result to my magento admin product manufacturer.

My question is that what should I do to query so that I can get the list of manufacturers of the product so that I can `sql join` in with `catalog_product_enity`'s `SKU`.

Does anyone has an idea about my case? I am new with magento so please be gentle with me.
Any help will be appreciated, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understood correctly.
If you want to get the manufacturer for a product, you don't need any query.
This should work. Let's assume that you already have the product in var `$_product`;

```
$_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');//this gets you the label
$_product->getManufacturer(); //gets the manufacturer id
```

**[EDIT]**
To get this for all the products do this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('manufacturer');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);//optional for only enabled products
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);//optional for products only visible in catalog and search
foreach ($collection as $product) {
   $sku = $product->getSku();
   $manufacturerId = $product->getManufacturer();
   $manufacturerLabel = $product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
   //do something with the values above - like write them in a csv or excel
}
```

Comment: I am needing a Query because I am trying to put it on excel file... But thanks for your answer Marius..

Comment: I've edited the answer with additional info on how to get this for all the products.

Comment: @gadss, did you ever work out a query that pulled manufacturer with associated products? I'm trying to do just this

Answer (score 1):

Little late, but this is what I came up with. Works like a charm.

```
SELECT cpe.sku, cpev.value, cpf1.manufacturer_value 
FROM catalog_product_entity cpe 
JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar cpev ON cpev.entity_id = cpe.entity_id
JOIN catalog_product_flat_1 cpf1 ON cpf1.entity_id = cpe.entity_id
WHERE cpev.attribute_id = 191
```

Comment: "cpf1.manufacturer" instead "cpf1.manufacturer_value" worked for me like a charm.

Comment: Disabled products do not appear in catalog_product_flat_N tables, which might be a showstopper.